# About solvable groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, gr.group-theory

Is it possible for a group (non-simple and non-abelian) that solvability of all of its proper subgroups leads the whole group to be solvable?

Comment: Minor edits.  In any case, the question may be too elementary for MO.

Comment: Sorry Jim for my elementary questions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. $SL(2,5)$ is a non-simple non-solvable group with the property that all its proper subgroups are solvable.

Comment: And that's the smallest example. Also called the binary icosahedral group. Maps onto $A_5$ with kernel of order $2$.

Answer (score 2):

An even simpler counter example is $A_5$.

I believe that finite simple groups in which every proper subgroup is solvable are called minimal finite simple groups and as I recall they were classified by J. Thompson before the calssofication of all finite simple groups. This classification is useful, I think J. Wilson used them to study identities of solvable groups.

Comment: The OP asked for a non-simple group.

Comment: Oops you are right.

Comment: J. Thompson, in his (famous) series of papers, dealt also with not necessarily simple groups, as far as I remember.

Answer (score 1):

The minimal non-solvable group surely has the property that all proper subgroups are solvable.

Comment: The only (very slight) subtlety is that the OP asked for a non-simple example.